# How do I sort a list of structures with a specific struct element?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How do I sort this structure correctly?

```
struct Person 
{
    public string Name;
    public int    Age;
}

List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

// Add several hundred records

// sort by age
People.Sort(Person.Age);
```

Comment: `Person` is a mutable struct which some people consider evil.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *lambda expressions* as well as *generics* here:

```
  struct Person { 
    public string Name; 
    public int Age; 
  }

  // generic List<T> is much better than deprecated List
  List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
  ...
  People.Sort((x, y) => x.Age - y.Age);
```

Another popular solution is *Linq*, but it *creates a new list* and so could be *not that efficient*:

```
  People = People.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for stating that LINQ creates a new list. This is important when lots of records are involved.

Comment: `x.Age - y.Age` could overflow if the `Age`s have opposite signs, so `x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age)` might be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ's [`OrderBy` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var sortedPeople = People.OrderBy(x => x.Age)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedPeople = People.OrderBy(p => p.Age)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> res = People.OderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
```